# Merge two data frames with null values

Tags: python, dataframe

I've two Data frames.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['SEDOL', 'MIC', 'ISIN', 'CUSIP','INV'],'value': ['', '', 'US2908861006', '290886100','F000000EU6']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['SEDOL', 'MIC', 'ISIN', 'CUSIP','INV'],'value': ['2316341', 'XNGS', '', '','F000000EU6']})
```

I want to merge them in such a way that if the values are same in both then it can consider value from any frame however if the value in any `df` is `NULL` it should pick from other if present. So in above case I wanted to generate o/p as

```
result_df = ({'key': ['SEDOL', 'MIC', 'ISIN', 'CUSIP','INV'],'value': ['2316341', 'XNGS', 'US2908861006', '290886100','F000000EU6']})
```

**SEDOL and MIC are taken from df2 and CUSIP and ISIN from df1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do that with `combine_first()`, it will combine two `DataFrame` or Series objects where missing values in one `DataFrame` or `Series` are conditionally filled with like-labeled values from the other `DataFrame` or `Series`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['SEDOL', 'MIC', 'ISIN', 'CUSIP','INV'],'value': ['', '', 'US2908861006', '290886100','F000000EU6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['SEDOL', 'MIC', 'ISIN', 'CUSIP','INV'],'value': ['2316341', 'XNGS', '', '','F000000EU6']})

df1.set_index('key', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('key', inplace=True)

result_df = df1.replace('', pd.NA).combine_first(df2.replace('', pd.NA)).reset_index()

print(result_df)
```

Comment: You welcome :) dont forget to validate the answer if it fit your problem.